# HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. UWP x86 ARM

Tags: c#, x86, arm, uwp

First: this is code:

```
        url = "ftp://user%40site.com:pass@ipblabla51/somefile.json";

        downloadOperation = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(url), file);

        Progress<DownloadOperation> progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(progresschanged);

        try
        {              
            await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(backgroundDownloader.Token, progress);
            /// some code
        }
```

When i'm running at x86  file is downloading OK, but when i'm running it on ARM Device, error is thrown:
on this line:

`await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(backgroundDownloader.Token, progress);`

with code: `HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.`

But.. when i change URL to 
`"https://eu.nicehost.com/files/somefile.....dasda.json";`

Code is running well.. so the problem is in URL parsing, 
`%40` is a `@` char. When i change it to `@`, background downloader can't authorize ftp client.

So how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

So.. if someone will have this trouble, he need to change hosting, or change account name, where there will not be any '%40' or other unicode chars.

I just changed a server ant it works well, so maybe thi is bug? who knows..